# Unhandled Rejection (Error) when inserting a checkbox on React App

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, checkbox

I am trying to display text, then a checkmark immediately right after it. However, I get the error "Unhandled Rejection (Error): input is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`."

I understand it shouldn't have children, so I have also tried moving it to before the `</li>` end tag. I also tried the idea of doing something like: `<input / >`, as I have tried searching for the answer online.

**UPDATE:** **After changing it to `<input / >` I now get the error: Parsing error: Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for . Would that mean I had to put a closing tag  and run into the same problem as before?**

I'm stumped! Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

```html
return (
 <div>
    <div>
        <table className = "className">
          <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th>Only avaliable Now</th>
          </tr>
              {this.state.time_array.map(item => (
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <li><b> {item.id}</b> 
                        <input type="checkbox" 
                          id={item.Name}>
                          checked={item.gotIt}
                        </input>
                        <ul>
                           <li>Where to find: {item.find}</li>                      
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </td>
              </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
  </div>      
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="checkbox" 
   id={item.Name}>
   checked={item.gotIt}
</input>
```

Code upside has some wrong useage of input tag;
Do change like below;

```
<input type="checkbox" 
   id={item.Name}>
   checked={item.gotIt}
/>
```

or

```
<input type="checkbox" 
   id={item.Name}>
   checked={item.gotIt}
>
</input>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I still get the same error. Does the placement of the checkbox stand out to you in any way perhaps?

Comment: Actually, I had a typo.

Now I get the error: Parsing error: Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for <input>

Would you happen to have any idea for this?

Comment: id={item.Name}>, last char ">" is redundant

Comment: Aw man, I completely missed that extra ">" and was looking for hours. Thanks so much!!!!